# EC2 - chmod: cannot access ‘mypemfile.pem’: No such file or directory

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2, chmod

I download `pem` file while launching `t2.small` instance. When I try to connect it via ssh it say no such a file in directory. But am sure that pem file is in directory.

```
    $ ls
      mypemfile.pem
    $ chmod 400 mypemfile.pem
      chmod: cannot access ‘mypemfile.pem’: No such file or directory
    $ ssh -i "mypemfile.pem" root@x.x.x.xx
      Warning: Identity file mypemfile.pem not accessible: No such file or directory.
      Permission denied (publickey).
```

How to track this issues? and any solutions?

**Note:** I created instance from AMI image shared by another account.

Comment: add the output of `ls -al` in that directory.

Comment: Any chance that the filename is not actually mypemfile.pem, for example it has trailing whitespace or other invisible characters?

Answer (score 0):

For sure the problem is because there is no "mypemfile.pem" file.

Recheck the availability of the file, if the file is available try to rename it or make a copy of it and try with the newly created file.

Hope it helps..

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out on Mac. So, this is what I had to do. When you created private key, my Mac saved is as whatever.pem.txt, so in order to connect to the AWS instance just add .txt extension to whatever AWS instructions tell you to do. For example:

chmod 400 yourfile.pem.txt ssh -I "yourfile.pem.txt" ubuntu@ecX-XX-XX-XXX-XXX.compute-1.amazonaws.com

This is for Mac users.

Best,